# QtRemoteObjects: get signal on host when remote node/replica disconnects

Tags: c++, qt, remoteobject, qtremoteobjects

I'm searching for a API of QtRemoteObject classes to detect when a remote client node (or even a specific replica, if possible) disconnects from the registry/host.

I've seen that this 4 year old question has no answers on stackoverflow: [QtRemoteObject receive signal in Host when Replicas are connected/disconnected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683684/qtremoteobject-receive-signal-in-host-when-replicas-are-connected-disconnected)

I know the networking model of QtRO is kind of peer-to-peer, so it's hard to detected new connections or lost connections of remote node, but such feature would really help on our project.

I've searched here in particular:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qremoteobjectregistry.html

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qremoteobjectnode.html

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qremoteobjecthost.html

thanks for your support,

when I close the client qt application, i don't seen any related log on the host side:
[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YPrM.png)

Comment: Do you have the code that listens and logs on [stateChanged signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qremoteobjectreplica.html#stateChanged) ?

Comment: Hello, I'm actually destroying the instance of the replica itself, so I can't listen for replica signals, I need a signal on the source side.